# UltiSnips not work: PYTHON caused GVim to EXIT

Tags: python, vim, ultisnips

Environments

- OS:Windos 7, x64 bit
- Vim: gvim74 from vim.org
- Python: Python 2.7.11
- UltiSnips: just downloaded from github

Gvim worked perfectly for me with SnipMate for a long time and lately I want to use UltiSnips instead. So i newly installed python on my PC, installed UltiSnips with Pathogen and just deleted snipmate, hoped it works well but it doesn't.

**The problem is: When I open gvim, it exits as soon as I press "i". Then I recovered gvim before I installed UltiSnips and simply executed a command on gvim like "python print "Hello"" or "python 1" or so, It does nothing but causes gvim to exit instantly, just like a executed "q!" command.**

OK It probably is a problem happens when gvim encounters python while does nothing with UltiSnips. Hope for suggestios or methods to solve this. Thanks all your guys.

Comment: Problem solved. I downgraded python from 2.7.11 to 2.7.9 and it worked well. Still don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I downgraded python from 2.7.11 to 2.7.9 and it worked well. – Cicero